# I moved a file and I want to know the previous directory for it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, files

Suppose I have a file I moved to someplace but I don't know where it was when I moved it.

How can I know it the previous directory?

Suppose I have changed the directory a lot so `cd -` will not work.

Then, how can I find it?

Comment: Depending on the `history` size you could find the previously used directories in there.

Comment: Welcome, when you say - *"I moved"* -, what do you mean exactly? Using the command `mv` in the shell? Could you give an example? If so **[edit]** the question, **don't add it in the comments**.

Comment: Did you move it using a shell command in a terminal, or using a graphical file manager? Do you believe that you moved that _specific_ file, or was the file moved as part of the contents of a directory that you moved as a whole?

Comment: In general, you can't, other than by browsing through your backups to see where the file appears (you do have backups, right?)

Comment: If you use `locate`, and your `locate` database isn't updated since you moved the file (on Linux, within a day, on BSD, usually within a week), then `locate` may be able to find the file's old location, assuming the file was publically available on the system.

Comment: if history, locate or mlocate couldn't get you what you want, then you can use  a recovery "tools" that will help you find your previous file location, just be careful with these tools.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** possible *in general,* because there is no guarantee that anything at all has recorded the original location of the file. I am not aware of a common mechanism for recording the location of files over time, but a few possibilities you could try include:

- Restore from backups.
- `locate name_of_file` - if mlocate is installed and the database is still stale, it should list the original file path. Of course, it will also list any other paths containing the same filename, so if the filename is not unique you'll have to check which of those paths still exist. If only one path is missing you can be fairly sure it's the original file path.
- If the file belongs to a package installed by a package manager I would simply reinstall the package and ignore/delete the copy.
- In the remote chance that someone has installed some form of logging of system activity you should be able to retrieve the information around the move action from that log.
- In the *very* remote chance that you are using a [versioning file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system) you can restore from that.

Answer (score -1):

In Bash,

```
history | grep -E 'cd | mv.*yourfilename'
```

The line(s) with "cd" command above or below the line containing "mv.*yourfilename" might give you a hint to the previous location. This doesn't work if the size of your history list is too small to contain the relevant cd and mv commands.

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors and other issues, but this still won't be much help. What if I `cd foo` and then ten thousand commands later do `cat filename`? Your command will show me `cd foo` and `cat filename` but I would have no way of knowing if the two happened close together.

Comment: If there was no other `cd` between `cd foo` and `cat filename`, then the shell should still stay in the directory `foo` - or not?

Comment: Also I forgot that my command worked on Zsh not Bash lol. Next time I will be much more careful. Thanks.